# Version mismatch for Searchd and Sphinxsearch

Tags: sphinx, cakephp-2.3

I am using CakePHP behavior plugin with sphinx server

`searchd error: client version is higher than daemon version (client is v.1.30, daemon is v.1.25)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you need to change the version of either the client or the server, so they match!

You could replease sphinxapi.php with the version from the package you installed of the server.

Or could find what version yuo have sphinxapi.php from and install the same server version.

Comment: Thanks, I just had to download the relevant version from .tar.gz source file. I installed from .deb :)